# Retrieving Devices and Printers Information from Control Panel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, wmi, controlpanel

I am using Python 3.9.12 and using `wmi` package.
I am trying to retrieve Model name of the mouse and keyboard for my tool. Whenever I am using `wmi.Win32_PointingDevice()` or `wmi.Win32_Keyboard()` in order to get the model name; I am getting **USB Input Device** or **Standard system devices**.

When I am using the following code, it is opening the GUI for devices and printers. Is there anyway to get the data without opening the GUI? I want the model name of the mouse and the keyboard.

```
import win32api
import win32con

win32api.WinExec('{0}\\control.exe printers'.format(win32api.GetSystemDirectory()),win32con.SW_NORMAL)
```

In control panel I can see the model of my mouse and keyboard mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The formatting of your question seems to be broken. Please check!